# Update NSTableView after cell modification

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nstextfieldcell

I'm a newbie in Objective c and Cocoa, and I have some troubles with using NSTableView (Cell based NSTableView). I have two questions

First I want to automatically to update some data in the tableview once the user hits enter after modifying a cell. I know how to update the data because I use a NSDictionnary and an arraycontroller to fill the tableView, but I don't know or rather I don't understand how to fire an action once the user modify a cell in a certain column.

To populate the tableview i use this code:

```
//Code for inserting data into my tableview when the user enter the "i" key

-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event
{
static int i = 1; // used as a counter
NSString * str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];
NSMutableString *str2 = [NSMutableString string];
[str2 appendString:@"Task "];
[str2 appendString:str];

if([event keyCode] == 0x22)
{
dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:false], @"check",str,@"numero",str2,@"designation",@"1",@"length",²"13/07/17",@"debpr",@"12/07/17",@"finpr",@"11/07/17",@"debpr1",@"12/07/17",@"finpr1",@"0",@"mgt", nil];

 checkState = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber  numberWithBool:false],[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i], nil];
 [_arrayController addObject:dict];

 [check setTag:i];

   }
   nbrTasks = i;
    i++;
     }
```

it works, I can modify my tableview cells but I cannot fire an action when editing is done. I tried to insert some action using the Cell View in the interface builder but it didn't work, nothing changes when I change the value in my TableView. Can someone explain it, using code examples? Because I'm really new to programming in Objective C and Cocoa and I don't know how to do it.

Secondly, I want to know how can I fire an action when selecting some rows, let's say I want to change a label when a specific row is selected. How do I do it?

Comment: I find it very silly that you direct people to a YouTube video instead of posting your own lines code.

Comment: Connect the action of the text field to the delegate of the table view. Check `NSTableViewDelegate` for selection change notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Willeke, but i finally used controlTextDidEndEditing method which was what i was looking for. Thank you very much again!